# Jfree chart contour plot chage values of ColorBar

Tags: java, plot, jfreechart, contour

i download this example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartContourPlotDemo2.htm and just change values in tmpDoubleYY, tmpDoubleXX, tmpDoubleZZ with my own but how to chage values into colorBar ?

Comment: Your question is likely to get closed as not a real question, if you don't provide enough information on what you are trying to achieve (and of course what you have tried)

Answer (score 0):

My question was how to change the range of colorBar (zAxis) with ContourPlot and the answer is :

```
public class Plot extends ContourPlot{

public Plot(ContourDataset dataset, ValueAxis domainAxis, ValueAxis rangeAxis, ColorBar colorBar, double colorBarMinValue, double colorBarMaxValue) {
    super(dataset, domainAxis, rangeAxis, colorBar);

    colorBar.setMaximumValue(colorBarMaxValue);
    colorBar.setMinimumValue(colorBarMinValue);
}
```

}